# Percentage by group with many columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with  round 100 columns from var1 to var100.

Grouping variable is a logical variable with 2 possible values, TRUE and FALSE.

What I am looking for it is to calculate the percentage of each variable from 1 to 100 variables by the grouping variable called `Group` that is a logical variable with only two values TRUE and FALSE.

**Sample**

```
Test_dataframe <- data.frame(Group=c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE),
                             var1=c(1,0,1,0,1,0),
                             var2=c(0,1,0,1,0,1),
                             var3=c(0,0,0,1,0,1))
```

**Expected result:**

```
 Result_dataframe <- data.frame(Group=c(TRUE,FALSE),
+                              var1=c(0.66,0.33),
+                              var2=c(0.33,0.66),
+                              var3=c(0,0.66))
```

**What I have tried so far.**

```
Result_dataframe  <-Test_dataframe  %>%  group_by(Group) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `mean` instead of `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
Test_dataframe %>% 
   group_by(Group) %>%
   summarise(across(everything(), mean), .groups = "drop")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  Group  var1  var2  var3
  <lgl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 FALSE 0.333 0.667 0.667
2 TRUE  0.667 0.333 0
```